What "Server" runs on application server for .Net and Python?
This is probably a dumb question but I was wondering what web-server runs on the application server for .Net and Python applications.
I know that we need to install ColdFusion server or PHP server if we want to run/serve those pages to the client side.
So what does one install on the application server so that a .Net code (whatever version of framework) can run and be served to the client browser?

Do you mean IIS ?

@PoulBak you can also just use Kestrel (the asp.net server)

@MarcGravell: Absolutely
